# Regex- match 3 or 6 of type

Tags: javascript, regex, hex

I'm writing an application that requires color manipulation, and I want to know when the user has entered a valid hex value. This includes both '#ffffff' and '#fff', but not the ones in between, like 4 or 5 Fs. My question is, can I write a regex that determines if a character is present a set amount of times or another exact amount of times?

What I tried was mutating the:

```
/#(\d|\w){3}{6}/
```

Regular expression to this:

```
/#(\d|\w){3|6}/
```

Obviously this didn't work. I realize I could write:

```
/(#(\d|\w){3})|(#(\d|\w){6})/
```

However I'm hoping for something that looks better.

Comment: `(\d|\w)` will match a lot of characters that aren't valid hex digits. Try `[\da-f]` (or `[\dA-Fa-f]`).

Comment: Note that what anubhava and biffen suggest is not expandable. The alternation you use `/(#(\d|\w){3})|(#(\d|\w){6})/` (the regex is bad, but the idea is correct) is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you expand on that?

Comment: @Biffen: You cannot use your approach to match exactly 2 digits or exactly 5 digits or exactly 14 digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest I could come up with:

```
/#([\da-f]{3}){1,2}/i
```

I.e. `#` followed by one or two groups of three hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/#[a-f\d]{3}(?:[a-f\d]{3})?\b/i
```

This will allow `#<3 hex-digits>` or `#<6 hex-digits>` inputs. `\b` in the end is for word boundary.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS6lI6/1)

Comment: Hello, 15 seconds after a question was posted? *Impossible*

Answer (score 1):

I had to find a pattern for this myself today but I also needed to include the extra flag for transparency (i.e. #FFF5 / #FFFFFF55). Which made things a little more complicated as the valid combinations goes up a little.

In case it's of any use, here's what I came up with:

```
var inputs = [
  "#12", // Invalid
  "#123", // Valid
  "#1234", // Valid
  "#12345", // Invalid
  "#123456", // Valid
  "#1234567", // Invalid
  "#12345678", // Valid
  "#123456789" // Invalid
];

var regex = /(^\#(([\da-f]){3}){1,2}$)|(^\#(([\da-f]){4}){1,2}$)/i;

inputs.forEach((itm, ind, arr) => console.log(itm, (regex.test(itm) ? "valid" : "-")));
```

Which should return:

> #123 valid
> #1234 valid
> #12345 -
> #123456 valid
> #1234567 -
> #12345678 valid
> #123456789 -